# When is the preimage of a continuous function measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The preimage of a Borel set under a continuous function is Borel, but the preimage of a Lebesgue measurable set need not be measurable.

Under what conditions is it true that the preimage of a general Lebesgue measurable set is measurable?

For example, is the preimage of a null set under a continuous function a null set?

Comment: If $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ then t $f^{-1}\{0\}=R$. If $g(x)=x$ for $x<0,\;$ and $  g(x)=0$ for $x\in [0,1],$ and $g(x)=x-1$ for$ x>1$ then $g^{-1}\{0\}=[0,1].$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but a homeomorphism that maps zero sets to zero sets in both directions will preserve Lebesgue Measurability.

Alternately, a homeomorphism which is Lipschitz in both directions (a so-called Lipeomorphism) preserves Lebesgue Measurability. This is because Lipschitz maps take zero sets to zero sets.

Finally, diffeomorphisms in general preserve Lebesgue Measurability. This is because they are *locally* Lipschitz. This follows from the $n-$dimensional Mean Value Theorem.

Also, it is not true that the continuous image of a zero set is a zero set. The Cantor Set is a zero set in $\mathbb{R}$, but yet there exists a continuous surjection of the Cantor Set onto any compact metric space.

Comment: Space filling curves are another example.

Answer (score 2):

Let $E$ be the standard "middle-thirds" Cantor set, and $S$ a "fat" Cantor set where at stage $n$, instead of removing the middle third you remove the middle $2^{n}$'th.  There is a continuous one-to-one function $F: [0,1] \to [0,1]$ that is a homeomorphism of $S$ onto $E$.  Let $A$ be any non-measurable subset of $S$.  Then $F(A)$ is a null set, but $F^{-1}(F(A)) = A$ is not measurable.

We may obtain $A$, for example, as the intersection of a [Bernstein set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_set) with $S$.